# Empty "s///" statement in sed - what does it do exactly?

Tags: shell, sed

I [found](https://web.archive.org/web/20161110085521/http://www.gnuvola.org/software/rcs/zow.txt) an old short shell script that piqued my interest:

```
cd ~/RCS
for f in .*,v
do printf '%3d  %s\n' \
  $(rlog -h $f | sed '/total revisions: /!d;s///') \
  $f
done | sort -nr
```

Looking at the sed script I noticed the empty `s` statement: `s///`. I had a look at the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) and didn't see this mentioned.

My guess is that the empty regular expression is matched against the pattern (i.e. "`total revisions:`"), matches, and then is replaced by nothing, i.e. it's deleted. Is that what happens? Is this a common idiom for sed scripting? If so, where can I read more about it?

Comment: See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses) from GNU sed manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man sed` on OS X:

> One special feature of sed regular expressions is that they can default to the last regular expression used.  If a regular expression is empty, i.e., just the delimiter characters are specified, the last regular expression encountered is used instead.  The last regular expression is defined as the last regular expression used as part of an address or substitute command, and at run-time, not compile-time.  For example, the command `/abc/s//XXX/` will substitute `XXX` for the pattern `abc`.

EDIT: From [your docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regexp-Addresses.html#index-empty-regular-expression):

> The empty regular expression `//` repeats the last regular expression match (the same holds if the empty regular expression is passed to the s command). Note that modifiers to regular expressions are evaluated when the regular expression is compiled, thus it is invalid to specify them together with the empty regular expression.

Comment: Thanks! I also found it in `info sed` Texinfo in section 3.2 ("selecting lines") but not in section 3.3 "regular expressions" or section 3.5 "the 's' command" where I was looking.